# How to invert a (simple ?) matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given an $n \times n$ matrix 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&a&0&0&\cdots&0\\
0&1&a&0&\cdots&0\\
0&0&1&a&\cdots&0\\
\cdots\\
a&0&0&0&\cdots&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

I'm tempting to prove that
$$A^{-1}=
\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{a^n+(-1)^{n-1}}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-a&a^2&-a^3&\cdots&a^{n-1}\\
a^{n-1}&1&-a&a^2&\cdots&-a^{n-2}\\
-a^{n-2}&a^{n-1}&1&a&\cdots&a^{n-3}\\
\cdots\\
-a&a^2&-a^3&a^4&\cdots&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

I've checked the result for small $n$ with Wolfram|Alpha ( see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inv%20%7B%7B1%2Ca%2C%200%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%20%7B0%2C%201%2C%20a%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%20%7B0%2C%200%2C%201%2Ca%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2Ca%7D%2C%7Ba%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D) and [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inv%20%7B%7B1%2Ca%2C%200%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%20%7B0%2C%201%2C%20a%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%20%7B0%2C%200%2C%201%2Ca%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2Ca%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2Ca%7D%2C%7Ba%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D)), and  I've tempted to prove the general result with brute force but I got lost in the calculation of the cofactors.  there is it some trick or some properties of matrix that can be used to prove ( or disprove ?) this result?

Comment: Have you tried just checking that $AA^{-1}=I$?

Comment: Yes, it seems to work. But I don't see why the signs of the entries depend in such way from the parity of $n$. maybe I lose something of stupid, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

A corollary to the Cayley-Hamilton theorem is that for an invertible matrix $A$ we have $$A^{-1}=-\frac{1}{k_0}(A^{n-1}+k_{n-1}A^{n-2}+\cdots+k_2A+k_1I).$$
$k_i$ indicates the coefficient of the ith power in the characteristic polynomial.

Now in your case the characteristic polynomial is $(x-1)^n-a^n$. So you just have to multiply it out and then use the formula above. I guess proof by induction from there, though the calculation might still be hairy...

Comment: the characteristic polynomial is $(x-1)^n - a^n$

Comment: ah - thanks - missed the little $a$ in the corner there - thanks for pointing that out, I corrected it.

Comment: yeah; the cyclic permutation matrix given by the positions with an $a$ has determinant varying as $(-1)^n,$ which goes a fair way to explain the sign changes the OP is getting.